# document.execCommand() doesnt paste rendered html

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

i'm working on a function to copy HTML content to a clipboard. If I paste this stored clipboard data to an WYSIWYG Editor, I'm getting just the plain html code. What i need is a rendered Link.

This is my function:

```
public copyLink(text, linkid) {

    const dummy = document.createElement('textarea');

    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.value = '<a href="' + linkid + '">' + text + '</a>';
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);

    this.snackBar.open('in Zwischenablage kopiert', 'close', {
      duration: 2000,
    });
}
```

Here the view after pasting in a common WYSIWYG Editor. First Line is what happens second what i need:

[image]

So how to control this render behavior of the Editor or Browser ?

Comment: I imagine this depends on the editor you're pasting into, it's entirely up to them whether they treat your pasted content as a link or plain text.

Comment: Right, what you copy is correct, what the editor does with that is a different thing (most likely for security reasons), so you won't be able to do anything about it unless the editor has some options to enable custom `HTML` code.